# How to execute a program continuously on a server? And which language to use?

Tags: php, mysql, perl, programming-languages

Okay this is my first post here so please forgive me if i mess something up.

I am trying to build a web program that will send email with content drawn from a db at a time specified in the db to a email address specified in the db. I am fluent in php & mysql and initially assumed i would base this program on those languages but i cant figure out how to use php to achieve my purpose. So i assume i will have to turn to another language, but i haven't the vaguest idea of which to turn to.

My other problem is that i don't know how to setup whatever script i end up making to run continuously.

Thanks for the suggestion Russ, to begin with it will be hosted locally either on my centos box or my xampp server, probably the later until it is working properly and i don't know about the future as it is just an idea right now.

EDIT: I actually did this in perl, it did end up a little different than originally planned but it worked so im happy.

Thanks to all who answered.

Comment: a good detail to add is the server type and OS and if you're hosting it or not.

Comment: Which part of your program is bothering you?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Decent first question, but remember that the devil is in the details, include relevant details in your question. The quality of the answers will improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerning only on how to schedule the send email function, you can try some open source scheduler like

http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/

Comment: I want to build my own as i have ideas for future use, but to begin with i want to figure out the basic functionality before trying more complicated things.

Comment: Well, it's just a scheduler. You have to implement your own email sending function. You just use it to fire the email sending at specific time.

Comment: Yes, i misunderstood you at first but i think you might actually have the answer now. I am looking at beanstalkd que manager. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Crontab with PHP can do what you want.
See: [Newbie: Intro to cron](http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

You can also write a PHP daemon to do the job.

Comment: But could a crontab be setup to run at times specified in a db? And i dont know anything about php dameons, will look into it.

Comment: PHP Daemon looks like the way to go. Thanks. Any ideas on where to start learning about them.

Comment: [Check this](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has events that can run every day/hour/minute.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

It's generally a bad idea to let the DB-server (MySQL) run external program though because that's a security risk.
So let the DB handle DB events and let crontab handle unix events.
Windows has the `at` command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Cronjobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronjobs) to achieve your goal.

You can find more info about how to use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cronjobs).